# Countable exhaustions have finite refinements implies finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set that satisfies the following property:

> For every countable family $\{U_{i}\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of subsets of $S$ for which $$S=\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}U_{i}$$there is a finite set $I\subset \mathbb{N}$ for which $$S=\bigcup_{i \in I}U_{i}$$

Does it follow that $S$ is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an infinite set. Then $A$ has a countable subset $B=\{b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots\}$.

Let $C=A\setminus B$. Let $U_i=\{b_i\}\cup C$. The $U_i$ cover $A$, but no finite subcollection of the $U_i$ covers $A$.

Answer (score 1):

(I’m assuming the axiom of choice here.) Suppose that $S$ is infinite; then there is an injection $f:\Bbb N\to S$. Let $A=S\setminus f[\Bbb N]$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=A\cup\{f(k):k<n\}$.

- What is $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$?
- Does $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ have a finite refinement?